# Assign a value to an attribute of a Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter object using XAML

Tags: vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2013, tfs, build

my BuildParameter is defined in my xaml build as follows:

```
<Activity this:Process.AdvancedBuildSettings=
"[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.BuildParameter(
    " { ""Attribute1"": """",
        ""Attribute2"": ""Value2"", 
        ""Attribute3"": ""Value3"" } "
 )]">
```

Now I want to update the value of **Attribute1** of my BuildParameter but I can't figure out how to do it.

It doesn't look like I can use an Assign block because these attributes names are not known by the compiler, so I want to use [BuildParameter's SetValue method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn234548(v=vs.120).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) but I'm not sure how to call this VB code in my xaml.

```
<Assign DisplayName="Update That Attribute">
    <Assign.To>
        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[AdvancedBuildSettings.Attribute1]</OutArgument><!-- this throws a compiler error because it doesn't know what Attribute1 is -->
    </Assign.To>
    <Assign.Value>
        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">""NewValue""</InArgument>
    </Assign.Value>
</Assign>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, the "*Assign*" workflow tool was not the tool I wanted. I needed to use the "*InvokeMethod*" workflow tool in order to invoke the **SetValue()** method of my **BuildParameter** object in my XAML build.

[MSDN InvokeMethod documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622976(v=vs.110).aspx)

[More details about the properties of InvokeMethod](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/364074/invokemethod-activity-in-workflow/)

So my solution looks like this:

```
<InvokeMethod DisplayName="Invoke That Method" MethodName="SetValue">
    <InvokeMethod.GenericTypeArguments>
        <x:Type Type="x:String" />
    </InvokeMethod.GenericTypeArguments>
    <InvokeMethod.TargetObject>
        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="mtbc:BuildParameter">[AdvancedBuildSettings]</InArgument>
    </InvokeMethod.TargetObject>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">Attribute1</InArgument>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[NewValue]</InArgument>
</InvokeMethod>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with XAML, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001739/modify-build-process-parameter-by-tfs-api-in-c-sharp) is a code snippet that using TFS API in C# to update the parameter name. You can use `WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters Method` and `WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters Method` to get parameter name, remove it, and add the new parameter name, maybe it can help you something:

```
string argumentName = "Attribute1";
var process = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(BuildDefinition.ProcessParameters);

if (process.ContainsKey(argumentName))                             
{
    process.Remove(argumentName);
    process.Add(argumentName, attributeValue);
    BuildDefinition.ProcessParameters = WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(process);
    BuildDefinition.Save();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking strictly for a XAML solution